# Permissions for root to copy files?

Tags: permissions

I am a user and I have files and folders saved on the hard disk drive of a computer running a Linux system.

I protected my data by restricting the permissions of access. If the root user decided to copy my files do the permissions of access need to be changed before root can copy my files? Is there any command line that can show me who access my saved data?

Comment: In general, root can do everything it wants. Even if there were logs showing modified files, it could still modify such logs

Answer (score 2):

root or physical access == access to your files, including copy, edit, and deletion.

Your only option would be encryption, although root can access the files when they are decrypted.

Comment: Thanks! How can I know if he accessed my files. Is there any command that can show me who is accessing my files? Does the root needs to change permisions before accessing the files?

Comment: you can try lsof, but root can hide or change the logs.

Comment: `lsof` lists *currently* open files. And no, root does not need to change any permissions. It can access all files, even if their permission string is `----------` (or `000` in octal notation).